# Is modifying sys.path the best way to handle a project specific module

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm (re)writing in python part of the testing tools supporting a large multi-language project, which are stored along side the project itself. At some point it becomes obvious that some code can be refactored out into its own package. But where should this be stored to be shared among the python tools?

In the python path, there is a company wide python-lib directory, but that shares with thousands what really is only important to tens of people, and more importantly, is not project specific.

For c test tools, we use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to our test libs, either pointing to our own build of the libs, or to some automated build output. I can modify `sys.path` to include any directory I want, and behave kinda like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, except easier for my teammates.

This doesn't seem pythonic. I am aware of virtualenv, though not well informed, but I have these concerns:

- Does this store multiple copies of the library, or is it simlinked? Python library size is negligible, but this is still frowned on by IT with our very large repositories.
- related, are the libraries kept in sync so bug fixes go to each tool?
- teammates would not want to run additional commands, `./gen_test_stimulus` is best, and `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../testlib` is ok. Multiple commands would face some resistance. Is wrapping the virtualenv commands in a bash script the way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is solely for testing purposes, updating your `PYTHONPATH` while running test code would be roughly the Python equivalent to updating `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for testing C code. In much the same way `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pushes some directories to the front of the shared object lookup path, [`PYTHONPATH` pushes specific directories to the front of `sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), and does so from the moment Python begins running (so you know there aren't any weird `site` triggered imports that might take place before you have time to update `sys.path` in your main module).

Using it for production is frowned upon (among other things, the same environment variable is read by both Python 2 and 3, so it can cause problems if any code at that location isn't compatible with both versions), but for test code, it's no more unreasonable than tweaking `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Virtual environments *might* work, but only if you could somehow publish the virtualenv company-wide; they store full copies of their local libraries, and (by default) prevent access to otherwise site-wide installed packages (to provide a clean environment). A test-centered virtualenv might want to pass the switch that allows access to system modules so it acts as a supplement to the system, not a replacement.

Activating virtualenvs in `bash`-like shells is simply a matter of running `source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate`, while deactivating them is just running `deactivate` (it's added to your shell as a function when the `activate` script is `source`ed). They're generally safer than modifying `PYTHONPATH` (among other things, they use version-specific sub-directories for each major.minor version of Python, so you won't accidentally run 3.6 specific code on 2.7), but you do need to write your test code as real packages (with `setup.py` files and all) to manage them properly. I personally think this is worth it (you'll need to learn the Python packaging mechanisms eventually), but it *is* a higher initial skill bar.